# Centering element on header bar that has floating <li> elements.

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a single header bar that is at the top of my website. Within the `<header>` tag I have an unordered list with a couple list items floating to the left, and another floating to the right. I want to be able to stick an element dead center of the header. What is the best way to do this? So far I have the page essentially set up like this:

```
<header>
  <ul>
    <li class="left">Item 1</li>
    <li class="right">Item 2</li>
  <ul>

  <h1>Title of site</h1>
</header>
```

And then the `<h1>` tag has text-align: center and margin-top: -45px, to put it on the same level as the list items. The issue is, the h1 isn't exactly centered. What is the best way to set up a header to accomplish this behavior?

Here is an example [jfiddle,](http://jsfiddle.net/4wxN5/1/) where you can see that the title isn't *really* centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good trick for getting something to align perfectly in the center when text-align:center; isn't an option is to do the following:

1) Get the exact width of the element you're wanting to center (div, hx tag etc)
2) Position the element absolute so that the item's position isn't affected by other elements
2) Set position to left:50% (the start of the element is exactly half way) then give a margin-left: negative half of the item's width.

Example
In your JS fiddle Your h1 is 106px wide. So for it's css you would put

```
header h1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:106px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-53px;
    top:6px;
    font-size: x-large;
    color: white;
}
```

[UPDATED JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4wxN5/4/)

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
h1 { position: absolute; top: 45px; left: 45%; }
```

or you could possibly try adding a new div above the header like this

```
<div id="h1wrapper">Your h1 goes here</div>
```

in your css

```
#h1wrapper { display: block; height: 0px; width: 100%; text-align: center; overflow: visible }
h1 { margin-top: 45px; font-size: 16px; }
```

Comment: left:45% will only center the element if the element's width is exactly 10%. Explanation: The inner-elements width at 10% means that it's center is 5% (50% of 10%); So for it's center to be in the middle of the parent element, then it's center needs to be at 50% of the parent. 45+(10/2)=50. If the element is anything but 10% wide it won't be center. See this JS fiddle to see what happens when it's not exactly adding up http://jsfiddle.net/ZXS7n/1/

Comment: I knew that, but I guess I shouldn't of posted it because it wasn't much help. I think my second suggestion would work like he wants though.